# Proving a Series is Bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that this question was asked already, but I have a slightly different question regarding this series or one close to it. I know that it is convergent but how do I prove formally that it is bounded, because if I can prove its bounded I can utilize the Monotone Convergence Theorem to say that it is convergent that way because it is monotonic.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^3}} $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^3}}=\dfrac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n^3}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^3}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}\le \frac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^3}(\sqrt{n})}=\dfrac{1}{2n^2}$

Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^3}}\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2n^2}$, which is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in order for a series to converge, its sequence of partial sums must also converge.  Because the series is a continuous sum of POSITIVE terms, its sequence partial sums cannot be decreasing even though its terms might be.  This is a really important distinction.

So yeah. Just find an upper bound for the sequence of partial sums (hint: use an algebraic limit trick) and you're there